# How do I shade the region between two curves in Grapher?

Tags: grapher

How do I shade the region (or area) between two curves in Grapher?

I'm looking for a way to do this in a 2D graph. The only example which comes close to this is the "Evaluation and Integration" example, but I can't figure it out.

For example, I would like to shade the region bound by these two curves:

```
y = x^2 - 2
y = 0
```

I'm assuming it's possible based on [this comment](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/930247?start=0&tstart=0).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First select both equations in the sidebar, and then *Equation » Integration…* in the menu.

[image]

In the dialog, it has preselected *Area Between Curves*. Confirm it.

You can change the color in the inspector window.

[image]

---

Since your second equation is `y=0`, you could just select the first one, and integrate it, selecting *Area* in the dialog. The result should look the same.

Comment: How do you undo this?

Answer (score 1):

Plotting `y > 0 & y < x^2-2` and `y < 0 & y > x^2-2`, we obtain the following

[image]